# Sagemaker Pipeline - Processing Step - SKLearn - missing SKLearn Extensions

Tags: scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I'm looking to automate SageMaker Pipelines so it can build, train and deploy models across environments. I'm not a data scientist and this area is very new to me so the struggle is real!

I've setup a pipeline that builds the code correctly but when it comes time to preprocess the step fails with the error **no module named 'sklearn extensions'**

Preprocess.py script below

```
from numpy import nan
from sagemaker_sklearn_extension.externals import Header
from sagemaker_sklearn_extension.impute import RobustImputer
from sagemaker_sklearn_extension.preprocessing import NALabelEncoder
from sagemaker_sklearn_extension.preprocessing import RobustStandardScaler
from sagemaker_sklearn_extension.preprocessing import ThresholdOneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# Given a list of column names and target column name, Header can return the index
# for given column name
HEADER = Header(
   column_names=[
       '1', '2', '3', '4', '5',
       '6', '7'
   ],
   target_column_name='6'
)


def build_feature_transform():
   """ Returns the model definition representing feature processing."""

   # These features can be parsed as numeric.

   numeric = HEADER.as_feature_indices(
       ['1', '2', '3', '4']
   )

   # These features contain a relatively small number of unique items.

   categorical = HEADER.as_feature_indices(
       ['1', '2', '3', '4']
   )

   numeric_processors = Pipeline(
       steps=[
           (
               'robustimputer',
               RobustImputer(strategy='constant', fill_values=nan)
           )
       ]
   )

   categorical_processors = Pipeline(
       steps=[('thresholdonehotencoder', ThresholdOneHotEncoder(threshold=8))]
   )

   column_transformer = ColumnTransformer(
       transformers=[
           ('numeric_processing', numeric_processors, numeric
           ), ('categorical_processing', categorical_processors, categorical)
       ]
   )

   return Pipeline(
       steps=[
           ('column_transformer', column_transformer
           ), ('robuststandardscaler', RobustStandardScaler())
       ]
   )


def build_label_transform():
   """Returns the model definition representing feature processing."""

   return NALabelEncoder()
```

Here is the script that calls the process pipeline.py

```
 # processing step for feature engineering
   sklearn_processor = SKLearnProcessor(
       framework_version="0.23-1",
       instance_type=processing_instance_type,
       instance_count=processing_instance_count,
       base_job_name=f"{base_job_prefix}/sklearn-job-preprocess",
       sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
       role=role,
   )
   step_process = ProcessingStep(
       name="PreprocessJobData",
       processor=sklearn_processor,
       outputs=[
           ProcessingOutput(output_name="train", source="/opt/ml/processing/train"),
           ProcessingOutput(output_name="validation", source="/opt/ml/processing/validation"),
           ProcessingOutput(output_name="test", source="/opt/ml/processing/test"),
       ],
       code=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "preprocess.py"),
       job_arguments=["--input-data", input_data],
   )
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First, You can install these extensions from pip as described [here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-scikit-learn-extension).

However, to use the I/O functionalities in the externals module, you need also to install `mlio` which is available only through `conda`.

Comment: The feature engineering file is generated by Sagemaker Autopilot